# Regular expression - get multiple matches into each group

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching, regex-greedy

I have a string like this:
`raw_string = "(a=1)(b=2)(c=3)"`

I'd like to match this and get values within each set of parentheses, and get each result in a group.
For example:

group 0 = `"a=1"`

group 1 = `"b=2"` and so on..

I've tried `/(\(.*\))/g` but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me with this?

thanks!

Comment: How are you applying the regex? From a quick search, it looks like you should be using `string.scan(/regex/)`. Also, you probably don't want `.*`, as its greedy and might eat up all your input. I would change it to `.*?`, or better yet, `[^)]+` (match any character that isn't the closing paren).

Comment: I think you just need [`s.scan(/\(([^()]+)\)/)`](http://rubular.com/r/mct68IbSif). Does [this code](http://ideone.com/Qwxc6Q) meet your needs?

Comment: We need a much better description of how you tried: Show us minimal code that demonstrates the problem. Stack Overflow isn't a "give me code" site, it's where we help you fix your code. We expect you've tried, ran into a problem, tried again, ran into another, and once you've exhausted your options then asked. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593 and [ask].

Comment: The downvote may be due to the fact that you say you have a string `(a=1)(b=2)(c=3)`, but without quotes that is not a string, or any Ruby object. You may think that's quibbling, but there's another reason you should include quotes. You should also assign the string to a variable (e.g, `str = "(a=1)(b=2)(c=3)"` so that readers can use the variable in comments and answers without have to define it (and you can't write `str = (a=1)(b=2)(c=3)`). Lastly, why not always use valid Ruby objects in examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = "(a=1)(b=2)  (c=3)"
```

As suggested in a comment by @stribizhev:

```
r = /
    \(       # Match a left paren
    ([^\)]+) # Match >= 1 characters other than a right paren in capture group 1
    \)       # Match a right paren
    /x       # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode

str.scan(r).flatten
  #=> ["a=1", "b=2", "c=3"]
```

Note `([^\)]+)` could replaced by `(.+?)`, making it a lazy match on any characters, as I've done in this alternative regex, which uses lookarounds rather than a capture group:

```
r = /
    (?<=\()  # Match a left paren in a positive lookbehind
    .+?      # Match >= 1 characters lazily
    (?=\))   # Match a right paren in a positive lookahead
    /x
```

Here the lookbehind could be replaced by `\(\K`, which reads, "match a left paren then forget about everything matched so far".

Lastly, you could use `String#split` on the right then left paren, possibly separated by spaces, then delete the first left and last right parens:

```
str.split(/\)\s*\(/).map { |s| s.delete '()' }
  #=> ["a=1", "b=2", "c=3"]
```

Wouldn't it be nice if we could write `s.strip(/[()]/)`?

Comment: ...@stribizhev had done so in a comment, but as he appears to not  be offering an answer... (You thought only one user could be referenced in a comment?)

Comment: I was busy with kids, now they are gone to bed :)

Comment: `s.strip(/[()]/)` is easily done with `s.tr('()', '')`.

Comment: @theTinMan. As you know, `strip` doesn't take an argument.  I've often wished it did, a string or a regex. Suppose, for example, I wanted to strip vowels from the beginning and end of a string. I'd like to be able to just write `str.strip(/[aeiou]+/)`. I know I could do that with `gsub` and a regex, but it I'd have to include anchors and "ors". There's probably a good reason `strip` is not designed that way, but I don't know what that would be.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the pattern with parentheses appears exactly three times (or a different fixed number of times), then it is possible, but if you intend that the pattern appears an arbitrary number of times, then **you can't**. **A regex can only have a fixed number of captures or named captures.**

Answer (score -3):

Just to show that you can get them into an arbitrary number of capture groups:

```
"(a=1)(b=2)(c=3)"[/#{'(?:\((.*?)\))?' * 99}/]
[$1, $2, $3]
#=> ["a=1", "b=2", "c=3"]
```

Comment: That is not arbitrary. It is fixed to 99. And no matter how large you set that number to, you cannot be sure (besides from machine limitation) if the generated regex has enough matches to match all the occurrences of the pattern until you actually match the string using a regex.

Comment: Sure you can, how about `str.length`?

Comment: Okay, that is nitpicking. To phrase my word more accurately: you cannot be sure until you examine the string in some way in advance, which defeats/lessens the purpose of using the regex to match the pattern.